# How to configure www to non-www redirect in Bitnami certified wordpress in GCP?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I have my site running in GCP, I need to edit the .htaccess file to create a redirect that redirects www to non www. How do I configure it?. I don't see .htaccess file in my website, I used a file manager plugin to access wordpress core files.

I read somewhere bitnami has htaccess configured differently,.How do I create the redirect?

BTW, my httpd-vhosts.conf file has the following lines of code,.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress.example.com
    ServerAlias www.wordpress.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName wordpress.example.com
    ServerAlias www.wordpress.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.key"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

It literally has example.com, not mydomain.com, should I be worried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not asking about `why my WordPress website not showing`, I assume that your WordPress website just working fine, so you can let the ServerName as is.

Furthermore, refer to the [document of Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

> Due to the fact that the virtual host with ServerName www.example.com is first in the configuration file, it has the highest priority and can be seen as the default or primary server.
>
> That means that if a request is received that does not match one of the specified ServerName directives, it will be served by this first .

Even though the ServerName might not match your real domain, **the first VirtualHost on *:80** will be used.

So if your WordPress website is working, I'll recommend that just keep it example.com.

For the redirect setting, refer to the [article on Bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/drupal/administration/redirect-custom-domains/#redirect-www-myapp-example-com-to-myapp-example-com)

You can try to use [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools) and use one of [text editors](https://tecadmin.net/linux-command-line-text-editors/) edit the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=permanent,L]
    ServerName wordpress.example.com
    ServerAlias www.wordpress.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=permanent,L]
    ServerName wordpress.example.com
    ServerAlias www.wordpress.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.key"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to restart the Apache HTTP Web Server in order to reload the setting file.

```
$sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Comment: yeah, my WordPress Website is working fine. I did all these steps when I installed SSL certificate, Does that mean it's not valid anymore?. And the above steps you have said apply also for https?

Comment: @shanganithi, you can use [ssllabs SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to check your SSL working or not; the httpd-prefix.conf also works for https since it has `%{REQUEST_SCHEME}` variable.

Comment: If there's any issue related to SSL, kindly open a new question and give error details in there, since the topic here is about `how to set up a redirect in Bitnami certified WordPress in GCP` :)

Comment: ssl is working properly in my website, but the traffic reduced significantly, That's why I was worried. and Google Search Console told me that my non www and www version are not configured properly.

Comment: @shanganithi understand, you can try to update the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-prefix.conf` to make redirect working then the Search Console issue should be solved.

Comment: I understood only now, But am sorry, The question should have been how to redirect www to non www. have updated the question, Can you please edit the code as such?

Comment: BTW, My httpd-vhosts.conf or httpd-prefix.conf , all are set to read only, how do i edit them?. If I edit and save using `wq!` command , am getting access denied.

Comment: Hi, Your answer works, but I need the other way around, Sorry for my previous question, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement redirection. A simple method is to modify your apache conf file. Replace example.com with your domain name.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    # Redirect everything arriving on HTTP to HTTPS
    Redirect "/" "https://example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    # Redirect anything that is not "example.com"
    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'example.com'">
        Redirect "/" "https://example.com/"
    </If>
</VirtualHost>
```

[Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

Read this link for common use cases to avoid:

[When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html)

You should modify `ServerName` to represent your server's domain name. This should match what you configure in WordPress Settings for `WordPress Address` and `Site Address`.

Comment: my httpd.vhosts.conf file has example.com in it., as I have posted the code above. Is that alright, or should I edit them?

Comment: Read the last paragraph of my answer. Yes you should change it.

Comment: Oh ., Ok. I got it. does that mean I didn't set up my ssl certificate properly?

Comment: Your SSL configuration looks correct. Are you having a problem?

Comment: Hi, Just a small doubt, where do I find this apache.conf?. All I have are banner.conf certs htaccess.conf httpd-app.conf httpd-prefix.conf httpd-vhosts.conf php-fm under the directory conf,.

Comment: @shanganithi You are displaying it in your question.

Comment: You mean the httpd-vhosts.conf?? that's the apache conf file?

Comment: It is the file that you configure virtual hosts. It varies based upon distribution.

Comment: Thanks, have done all these steps, edited the httpd-vhosts.conf. But Am not getting redirects.

Comment: Look at the Apache log files for problems. Use `curl -i` to debug. Without seeing your file, I can only guess. Edit your question with a new UPDATE section.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bitnami wordpress that you could configure directly in wordpress cause the only .htaccess that has wordpress is in

/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/akismet/.htaccess

I suggest you change the name site, here is the [link](https://en.support.wordpress.com/changing-site-address/) of wordpress to do it.
Also consider in your dns records have the records

wordpressexample.com A external IP
www.wordpressexample.com CNAME wordpressexample.com

This is in order to enable me to get access to your website from both links.